# ffmeg x264 presets not working

Tags: ffmpeg

Trying to capture screen to video file encoded with lossless x264:

```
vic@vic-X202E ~/Desktop » ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 15 -s 1366x768 -i :0.0 -sameq -vcodec libx264 -preset:v ultrafast test.mkv
ffmpeg version 0.8.4-6:0.8.4-0ubuntu0.12.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Nov  6 2012 16:51:11 with gcc 4.7.2
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
[x11grab @ 0xc2bf60] device: :0.0 -> display: :0.0 x: 0 y: 0 width: 1366 height: 768
[x11grab @ 0xc2bf60] shared memory extension  found
[x11grab @ 0xc2bf60] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, x11grab, from ':0.0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1357648973.267658, bitrate: 503562 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: rawvideo, bgra, 1366x768, 503562 kb/s, 15 tbr, 1000k tbn, 15 tbc
Unrecognized option 'preset:v'
Failed to set value 'ultrafast' for option 'preset:v'
```

Another try:

```
vic@vic-X202E ~/Desktop » ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 15 -s 1366x768 -i :0.0 -sameq -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast test.mkv  
ffmpeg version 0.8.4-6:0.8.4-0ubuntu0.12.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Nov  6 2012 16:51:11 with gcc 4.7.2
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
[x11grab @ 0x2482f60] device: :0.0 -> display: :0.0 x: 0 y: 0 width: 1366 height: 768
[x11grab @ 0x2482f60] shared memory extension  found
[x11grab @ 0x2482f60] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, x11grab, from ':0.0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1357648985.325860, bitrate: 503562 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: rawvideo, bgra, 1366x768, 503562 kb/s, 15 tbr, 1000k tbn, 15 tbc
Unrecognized option 'preset'
Failed to set value 'ultrafast' for option 'preset'
vic@vic-X202E ~/Desktop »
```

Something broken? Using Kubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please [don't use the `same_quant` option](https://superuser.com/questions/478549/what-is-the-sameq-or-same-quant-option-in-ffmpeg-does-it-mean-same-quality). It doesn't achieve what you think it does.

Now, to achieve lossless compression, you need to specify a [constant quality](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/werner.robitza/crf.html) of 0 with `-crf 0`.

```
avconv -f x11grab -r 15 -s 1366x768 -i :0.0 \
-c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 \
test.mkv
```

See the [x264 encoding guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for more options.  If you don't have x264, you need `libavcodec-extra`.

---

Note that FFmpeg and Libav should treat this command the same. The problem with your system is that your FFmpeg version is terribly outdated. You should [compile it yourself](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide) or download a [static build from the homepage](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html). Both would include x264.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `avconv` in place of `ffmpeg`. (The relationship between these two forks in Ubuntu appears to be a [complex issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/who-can-tell-me-the-difference-and-relation-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv/9477756#9477756)).

On my 12.10 system I have both the executables for `ffmpeg` and `avconv`, but only preset files for `avconv` (in `/usr/share/avconv`).

Try:

```
avconv -f x11grab -r 15 -s 1366x768 -i :0.0 -same_quant -codec:v libx264 -pre:v ultrafast test.mkv
```

Comment: I am getting `"Unknown encoder 'libx264'"`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libx264-120` ?

Comment: ok, it worked after i installed package `libavcodec-extra-53`. Thanks!

Comment: The command you gave doesn't achieve lossless compression.